# Missing glVertexAttrib functions in Qt

Tags: c++, opengl, qt5

I am currently updating my code to use Qt's `qopenglfunctions_4_3_core.h` functions for rendering. I am currently facing an issue while updating how I set static vertex attributes using `glVertexAttrib*`, as this function apparently doesn't exist in 'qopenglfunctions_4_3_core.h'. I have been trying to find an alternative to this, but I can't seem to find anything about the correct way to set static vertex attributes without calling the `glVertexAttrib*` functions. Most of the alternative ways I've been able to think of involve uniforms or filling a VBO with a single value, which I am trying to avoid. What is the best way to set static vertex attributes using the functions available in `qopenglfunctions_4_3_core.h`?

Comment: You don't need `glVertexAttrib`. Use [`QOpenGLVertexArrayObject`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglvertexarrayobject.html). The OpenGLcore profile API doesn't provide `glVertexAttrib`.  See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)

Comment: @Rabbid76 How would I then use QOpenGLVertexArrayObject to then set static vertex attributes? It looks to me like QOpenGLVertexArrayObject  is just a wrapper for VAOs, which I am already using. I just have some vertex attributes that I don't need to change for each call to my vertex shader like they would if I were to use a VBO with glVertexAttribPointer. Is there a way to make glVertexAttribPointer repeatedly feed the same element to the vertex shader?

Comment: It sounds as if you're looking for [`glVertexAttribDivisor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribDivisor.xhtml)? If so, have you tried using `QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core`? I suspect it provides the API you require but, rather than documenting the huge list individually they've simply stated that the class `"...provides all functions for OpenGL 4.3 core profile"`.

Comment: @G.M. I am indeed using `QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core`. I will give `glVertexAttribDivisor` a try, I think that should provide me with the functionality I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @G.M. The way I am understand `glVertexAttribDivisor` is that I need to set the divisor for my static attributes to 0. According to the documentation, this will cause the attribute to "advance once per vertex". What if I don't want it to advance once per each vertex, since the same data needs to be passed for each subsequent vertex? From my understanding, in order for this to work I would have to fill a buffer with duplicate values for each vertex within each instance, I need to avoid having duplicate data stored. Sorry if I am misunderstanding how this works.

Comment: Have a look at [this example of OpenGL instancing](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing).  While probably not *exactly* what you're looking for it should serve to illustrate the basics of what `glVertexAttribDivisor` actually does.